# How can I use more than one comparison with the .equals function or is there another function that I can use to check?

Tags: java, comparison

BTW, this is only a short version of my code, the only problem I have is from `.equalsIgnoreCase` over.  I have tried the pipe operator || and that has not worked for "or" either.  Let me know, thanks.  Its in Java too.

```
if(sWord.substring(0,sWord.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("ch","sh","s","x","z"       
    {
        lblPluralOutput.setText(sWord + "es");
    }           
}
```

Comment: `sWord.substring(0,sWord.length())` look like a bug to me

Comment: `Arrays.asList({"str1","str2" .."strN"}).cointains(yourString)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do it directly like that. Put all possible values in an array and check your string is in that array or not.

```
String[] items ={"ch","sh","s","x","z"};
for (String item : items) {
    if (sWord.substring(0,sWord.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
       lblPluralOutput.setText(sWord + "es");
        break; 
    } 
}
```

More over `sWord.substring(0,sWord.length())` again gives you same string back. Is it a typo ?

Comment: I made it recursive, so I keep checking with the substring function one character at a time.  I dont know the input words and I have to deal with them nomatter what the length.

Comment: Recursive or not, `sWord.substring(0,sWord.length())` always gives you the whole string (you are getting a substring which takes from the first to the last character == the whole string).

Answer (score 1):

Those functions only take one parameter.

If you want to check whether a string is equal to either of two things, you need to check separately:

```
if (a.equals(b) || a.equals(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [String#equalsIgnoreCase(Str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) cause only receives one parameter. But you can
make your util method.

Something like this. We can make it generic.

```
public final class UtilClass{
    private UtilClass(){}

    public static <T> boolean  isSomeOneEquals(T myParam, T ... a){
        return Arrays.asList(a).contains(myParam);
    }
}
```

So in your example just put:

```
UtilClass.isSomeOneEquals( sWord.substring(someIndex,sWord.length()).toLowerCase(), "ch","sh","s","x","z" );
```